# Unable to add pipe "|" to menu items using tailwind css

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to add a pipe to my menu links, using tailwind ::before pseudo element but it doesn't work.

```
<a className='text-xl font-normal before:content-["|"] before:pl-8 bg-white font-open-sans'>home</a>
```

The above result in the following

[image]

How can I add the pipe properly with padding/margin between text and pipe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add the padding to the other side of the pipe, changing `before:pl-8` to `before:pr-8`.

Working version here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/G5IqVTI5Rg